# Remove labels but keep legend in a pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I remove the labels from a [pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) but keep the legend ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [15, 30, 55]
labels = [1, 2, 3]

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=72)
plt.pie(x, labels=labels)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('pie_1.png')
```

[image]

Comment: How about to move labels in pie to legend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove the `labels` argument from the pie and add it to the legend. Instead of

```
plt.pie(x,labels=labels)
plt.legend()
```

use

```
plt.pie(x)
plt.legend(labels=labels)
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [15, 30, 55]
labels = [1, 2, 3]

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=72)
plt.pie(x)
plt.legend(labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [IMCoins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48791745/1356000), which is the best way to proceed, you could also keep your current code, but delete the labels from the pie chart.

```
x = [15, 30, 55]
labels = [1, 2, 3]

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=72)
patches, texts = plt.pie(x, labels=labels)
plt.legend()
for t in texts:
    t.remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd create a custom legend, instead of letting matplotlib creating its own automatic one. You are now asking matplotlib to plot the labels using `labels=labels` in `plt.pie()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [15, 30, 55]
labels = [1, 2, 3]
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'grey']

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=72)
patches, texts = plt.pie(x, colors=colors)
plt.legend(patches, labels)
plt.show()
# plt.savefig('pie_1.png')
```

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to set the label distance to **None**, as suggested in the matlplotlib.pyplot.pie documentation.

This worked very well in my case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [15, 30, 55]
labels = [1, 2, 3]

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=72)
plt.pie(x, labels=labels, labeldistance=None)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('pie_1.png')
```

Comment: You're a live saver. I had some whacky setup where there was no other way than this to remove the labels from the pie chart, but keep the label data for other purposes :-)